# Just want Jenkins to do a Git clone

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm new to Jenkins and Git.  I'm producing a Freestyle Project and the repo that is produced in the build looks like its selecting an unwanted branch.  I'd like Git just to "git clone" and that's it.  I look in the "console Output" and it looks similar to this:

https://www.guru99.com/images/1/091318_0458_HowtoCreate11.png

I try running the git commands in another repo and get a "no match" in the fetch command due to the +ref arguments.

So I want to keep it simple.  If Jenkins is doing a clone, what options do I need to deselect to stop the fetch command?  My goal is just to do a clone and none of these additional commands

Sure. I think I just dont understand refspecs in respects to my clone location. When I do a:

git clone https://githubs.com/kriru/firstJave.git

branch -a

returns:

*develop
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/develop
remotes/origin/develop
remotes/origin/software/RELEASE_1

The error where I think Im defining my refspecs incorrectly is:

fetch --tags --progress https://githubs.com/kriru/firstJave.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

git: No match.

My understanding is +refs/heads should point to the main branch and refs/remotes/origin/* should point to my local.  Based upon my branch -a I dont think Im pointing to the main branch.  I thought that would happen with the 'git clone' command.  Im wondering if I need to set an order to point to the main branch and then software/RELEASE_1.  I think the default Jenkin fields entered is incorrect

Comment: Does the fetch cause the build to fail or does it simply display the "no match"? Most of the time you can simply ignore this block and treat it as a more advanced version of a git clone. If you really need to only clone the repo without anything else the easiest would be to disable the default checkout and just do a "git clone repo" in whatever shell as the first step of the job.

Comment: I repeat the commands from the Console Output in a clean repo outside of Jenkins. I'm trying to see if I could manually do what Jenkins is doing. That's when I get the "no match" I did try cloning the repo but I have key permission denials. Somehow one/some of these radio buttons are adding these extra git commands. Just can't find the hidden switch :/

Comment: Can you post your exact error messages?

Comment: @Robj It is best to edit your question: you can easily format your additional data that way, rather than bury them in the comments.

Comment: Thanks. I'm kinda new